# Identifying correct answer for multiple submissions in a live trivia app- without going back to DB repeatedly

Tags: node.js, database, security

I'm trying to create a Live Trivia app in Nodejs but I'm having mixed thoughts on how to check for the correct answer. 
Since the questions are answered in a live environment and hence submissions from all the users come in a short period of time(say 10-15secs).

Clearly I don't want to be going back to the database for checking the correctness of the answer submitted. That could put the db under a lot of strain.

Presently I am checking the answer checking locally on the client-side and then hitting my server and communicating whether the user answered correctly or not. Does this process have security risks? Right now I am assuming so as the user could simply make an api request by setting the isAnswerCorrect value to true - and this would get sent to the database. Also since the answer is briefly present on the client side, it could be exposed.Also the insecurities might appear trivial as I have limited understanding of the front end technologies. In that case can someone kindly point out what could be a secure way.

Also my random thoughts have been around using pub-sub azure service bus(or kafka) or using an in memory db like redis.
What would be a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server should determine whether the answers are correct, not the client, otherwise if the someone hacked your client it could notify the server that he answered correctly all the time.

I would suggest you to store the Q&As in a dedicated database. You don't have to frequently access your db in every request, just load the set of  Q&As to the cache (your server memory) and use it to response user's answers.
Represent the set of Q&As in your server in a fast access structure, like a map from question-id to answer-id/hash/Q&A object/however you represent your answers, prefer to use the same types are used by the client requests.

Unless you deal with millions of different questions, you should be able to load all of them on memory. If new questions may be added over time, just provide a method of searching in the database in case of non-existed question in your cache (then load it to the cache).

If you worry about massive loads of requests to the server with some peaks it can't handle correctly, you can use Kafka as a back pressure remedy to balance the requests handling.
This can be done by handling requests in a streaming process (KafkaConsumer) which can allow some delays because Kafka saves the delayed requests in a queue for later processing (Topic/Partition).

Comment: Excellent suggestions. For server side caching I am assuming Redis would do the job and Kafka could handle peak request loads which can be consumed over a period of time. Again thanks for the answer.